# Discord.py: How can I get the bot role and change his color?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots, roles

So I want my bot to take his own role and edit it to change the color, but I didn't find anything.
I tried  to get it with `discord.utils.get` under `on_ready` but it doesn't work.
Can you guys help me??

Comment: bots cannot edit their own role, whatever you do it'll not be possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless a user is the owner of a guild (server), they cannot edit their top role. Therefore, this is a bit harder to achieve. What you are going to want to do is get the bot's second to top role, then edit the color of that role.

```py
@bot.command()
async def color(ctx):
    bot_member = ctx.guild.get_member(bot.user.id)
    if len(bot_member.roles) < 3:  # bot needs 3 roles, @everyone, the bot integration role, and a role to edit
        return await ctx.send('Give me another role please!')
    else:
        role_to_edit = bot_member.roles[-2]  # the second highest role
        await role_to_edit.edit(color=discord.Color.blue())  # you can choose what you want to change this to, i used blue as an example
```

For this to work, the bot has to have at least 2 roles. The top role should be set to the default (invisible) color, so editing lower role colors will edit the color of the bot's shown color role.